# How to detect the multiple webservers running in an auto-scaling environment on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

Is there any way to detect number of EC2 webservers running on a machine by checking the /var/log directory in redhat 6?

I checked on the internet which says about using cloudwatch to monitor logs using a script. But I don't know how to use it. How should I detect the number of EC2 webservers without using cloudwatch?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is an "EC2 webserver" specifically? What is the difference between an EC2 instance and a "machine" specifically?

Comment: Basically, I want to detect the multiple webservers running in an auto-scaling environment on AWS.

Comment: Are you trying to check for unauthorized webservers running on your instance? Are you trying to figure out how many instances are in your web scaling group?

Comment: I am trying to figure out, how many instances are in my web scaling group?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/auth-and-access-control-cwl.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html

Comment: A "machine" would be a single EC2 instance. In your auto-scaling environment each instance ("machine") will have one web server service running on it. You can't look on a log file in a single server to determine how many other servers happen to exist. You need to utilize the AWS API to query for the current number of instances in your auto-scaling group. You seem to be confused about what an auto-scaling group does. It creates entirely new servers for you. It doesn't start new webserver service instances on a single server, what would be the point of that?

Comment: @MarkB Cloudwatch can be used for this if the op wants centralized log system for multiple web servers running in an environment.

Comment: @Demonking28 So you recommend parsing out all the separate log files and trying to determine some how a method to exclude logs from servers that have been terminated, instead of just using the API that is created for this sort of query? CloudWatch Logs is a great for log aggregation, but it is terrible for answering the question of "how many web servers are currently running".

Comment: If a CLI solution would suffice, you can use aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name xyz to enumerate the instances in your ASG (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html)

Comment: @MarkB Actually the op wanted a db for logs aggregation .He deleted that comment.